# How can I find current element text on mouseover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg id="a" height="210" width="400">
  <path id="b" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

When mouse is over from b, I want to that code (path id="b" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" ).How can I get it using jquery?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

```
var path = $("#b")[0].outerHTML; // <path id="b" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"></path>
```

Then combine that with hover:

```
$("#b").hover(function() {
    console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r8v70Lnk/)

As pointed out, this won't work in IE because it doesn't follow [specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/innerhtml/raw-file/tip/index.html#dom-element-innerhtml). You can workaround this by cloning the `<path>` element, appending it to the HTML body to make it part of the DOM, then grabbing the rendered HTML from there.
**Note:** This won't be an exact *representation* of the HTML because it's out of context. For example, it contains the `xmlns`, but since it's a jQuery object you can modify it how you like:

```
$("#b").hover(function() {
    // Create a clone of the <path>
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    // Append it to the <body>
    clone.appendTo("body");
    // Wrap it in a containing <div> ... you'll see why in a minute
    clone.wrap("<div>");
    // Now we grab the innerHTML of that containing <div> - outerHTML won't work
    console.log(clone.parent().html());
    // Prints: <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="b" d="M 150 0 L 75 200 L 225 200 Z" /> 

    // Now remove our temporary element again...
    clone.parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: this is not working in IE.. can you please check in IE

Comment: @AkbarBasha Typical IE :) I've updated the answer with an alternative